# Inequality matrix norm

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ random matrix $A=rand(n,n)$. Let $\alpha=max_{i,j}|a_{ij}|$ (i.e, $\alpha$ is the largest entry in $A$ in absolute value).I need to show that  $\ \alpha < \|  A \|_{2}$.

I am trying to use the fact that $\|A\|_{2}=\sigma_{max}$ in my proof where $\sigma_{max}$ is the largest singular value of $A$, but I wasn't successful. Does anyone know how to prove this inequality?

Comment: Well, if $A=0$ you cannot have strict inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the inequality will not be always strict. For instance, any diagonal matrix will give you equality.

Let $k,h$ be the coordinates of $\alpha$. Let $\delta$ be a number such that $\alpha=\delta a_{k,h}$, and let $e_j$ be the vector with a $1$ in the $j$ position and zeroes elsewhere. Then, by Cauchy-Schwarz, 
$$
\alpha=e_k^TA(\delta e_h)\leq\|A\|_2\|e_k\|_2\,\|\delta e_h\|_2=\|A\|_2.
$$

Comment: Poetic inequality?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow :)

Comment: Sorry, I was playing on the misspelling of the word Cauchy which looked a little like Chaucer (British poet)...

Comment: Oh, now I see it. I hadn't even noticed. Poetic inequality indeed  :D

Comment: I need a life :-).